# How can I send the full Taxonomy Hierarchy from Content Hub to Sitecore?

Tags: content-hub, taxonomy

I am currently working through building my Taxonomy in Content Hub and working through sending it to Sitecore through CMP. As of right now I have a trigger set up that sends any new Assets from Content Hub to Sitecore along with my Taxonomy field in question. I have the incoming taxonomy set up as a `Tag Field Mapping` in Sitecore. However, it always imports the tag the same way no matter what `Leaf Node` or `Store Tag Name` options I have set.

When looking through the API I have noticed that the relationship field name: `TaxonomyName` only imports the assigned value of my Taxonomy and not the full hierarchy path. As you can see here:
[image]

I would assume that I do not have one of the configurable items set up correctly in Content Hub, but I am not sure exactly what I am missing.

Can anyone please tell me what settings I need on the Taxonomy field to have access to the full hierarchy path in Sitecore?

**EDIT 1**

I figured I would try to expand on my question to hopefully be a little bit more explicit with what I am looking to do/trying to understand.

Looking in the the CMP documentation for Content Hub here: [CMP documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/connect-for-ch/40/connect-for-content-hub/tag-field-mapping-settings.html)

It provides all of the settings for a `Tag Field Mapping` to achieve different types of taxonomy imports as Sitecore Tags. In th the documentation it says:

> For example, say you have a taxonomy in the content hub that has the
> hierarchy Company/Sitecore/Content Hub/Blog. You also have an item
> that has been tagged with Blog.

Followed by showing this table:
[image]

I currently have a hierarchy taxonomy assigned to my asset with the path `Top Level Brand/Accessory`. According to the documentation above... I would think that if I have `Non-Leaf Node` set to `Enable` and Store Tag Name Option As`set to`Node Name`I should get the following tags associated to my imported item:`Top Level Brand`and`Accessory`.

Am I missing something here? Can anyone provide any insight on what needs to be done to achieve what I am looking for?

**EDIT 2**

And for just to clarify. I am getting the tag coming through, but not the full hierarchy that is to be expected. Here is a screenshot of what I am getting:

[image]

When I should be expecting something like `Brand.Advertisement`.

Answer (score 1):

I am quiet new to Content Hub and now about Sitecore Experience but I may be able to help you with the Content Hub API.

It seems that with the Content Hub API you will not have the full hierarchy but just the parent and children of your entity. So, in your example, your entity id is 34159 (from self.href) and its parent id is 34210 (from parent.self).

Isn't the href of the parent object what you are looking for ?

**EDIT**

Content Hub REST API Documentation :
https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.0.x/integrations/rest-api/resources/Entity.html#get-apientitiesid

Comment: thank you for the response! I am also pretty new to Content Hub and am trying to get my feet wet. I checked out the href for the parent object and didn't really see anything I was looking for at first glance. I updated my question above to provide more information on what I am trying to achieve. Please review and let me know if that makes more sense as to what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: @scapegoat17 I understand the same as you of the documentation you have provided, but I don't know anything with Sitecore Experience.
But your result looks like a GET on the Content Hub Rest API  [see the doc here](https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.0.x/integrations/rest-api/resources/Entity.html#get-apientitiesid)
have you tried to open the href links in a browser to see the JSON data ?

Comment: Yes I have tried. The only thing that I see as relative is the `path` property however, I don't see how any of that ties back to Setting up a `Tag Field Mapping` in Sitecore. This is my current roadblock right now. I do not see anything in documentation that specifies any more information on the matter...

Comment: Also just to add on to the above. I attached a screenshot of my `Tagging` section under `EDIT 2`. To show that I am getting tagging to come through but not with the full hieratical path as expected and what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same exact problem, what was causing this functionality not to work for us was having a dot character in the name of the taxonomy, e.g. we had Content.Topic as the taxonomy name, here is what it looked like:

[image]

I've had Sitecore support confirm this as a bug, to fix it we simply renamed our taxonomy to Topic rather than Content.Topic, I'm not sure if you've set this up in a similar way or not but it might be cause of your problem

Edit:

On second glance, I can see the API response is slightly different to mine as well, here is the relation in my API response, there is just a single href:

[image]

My setup in the schema looks like this:

[image]
[image]

When I added this member, I selected the Taxonomy option, I didn't really have to change any of the settings,

My Sitecore mapping looks like the following:

[image]

The tagging should look something like this if it's working:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! Perhaps it could be part of the problem. However, I removed the dot character from the taxonomy and am still running into the same problem. I was wondering if you would be able to post the settings you used for adding the taxonomy to the schema and perhaps a screenshot of what the relations section looks like from the `Entities API`? Thank you so much for reaching out! I am hoping you might be able to get me on the right track still!

Comment: No problem I've just added some screenshots to my original answer, on second glance I can see there's a difference in the entities API response which might be causing your issue, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed update! The only two differences I can see between your instance and mine is that 1) yours is a `M.Content` and mine is `M.Asset` 2) Your tagging goes to `TagRepository and mine goes to the `CachedItemTagRepository`. Would you happen to know if this is something that could hinder that tagging structure from working? I wonder if it being an `M.Asset` would be why your API looks a little different from mine?

Comment: Also just to add on to the above. I attached a screenshot of my Tagging section under EDIT 2. To show that I am getting tagging to come through but not with the full hieratical path as expected and what you have.